# Output multiple random passwords using Python

Tags: python, passwords

Soon, I am going to need to generate a few hundred random passwords for users and I'd like to automate that as much as possible. So far, I have been able to find Python password generators for a single output, but what I would like is for it to output a batch of random passwords at once. So far, this is what I have (thanks to previous comments in the Stack Overflow community!). Any input will be greatly appreciated.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperalphabet = alphabet.upper()
pw_len = 8
pwlist = []

for i in range(pw_len//3):
    pwlist.append(alphabet[random.randrange(len(alphabet))])
    pwlist.append(upperalphabet[random.randrange(len(upperalphabet))])
    pwlist.append(str(random.randrange(10)))
for i in range(pw_len-len(pwlist)):
    pwlist.append(alphabet[random.randrange(len(alphabet))])

random.shuffle(pwlist)
pwstring = "".join(pwlist)

for i in range(60):    
    print(pwstring)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: You haven't specified your problem -- putting code in a loop is an introductory technique in any language, something you learn from a tutorial, not Stack Overflow.  You haven't described any particular problem with your code; for simple looping, what you've posted is not a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please review the intro tour, clarify your problem, and post again when you're ready.

Comment: "Any input" is a clear signal that this is not yet a Stack Overflow problem.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine for what you want to do:

```
import secrets
import string

passwords_generator = (string.ascii_letters  
                        + string.digits 
                        + string.punctuation)

for i in range (20):
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(passwords_generator) for i in range(20))  
    print(password)
```

You can find all the necessary information about the code [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).